# one to many mapping in hibernate for a messaging service

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have two JPA entities: `User` and `Message`.
Each `Message` has one `sender` and one `receiver` of type `User`. And on the other side each `User` has two sets of type `Message`: `inbox` and `outbox`.

`Message`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "MESSAGES_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SENDER")
    private User sender;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECEIVER")
    private User receiver;
    private String subject, content;
    private Date sdate;
    //getters and setters
}
```

All the properties which not being mapped with an annotation has he same name as the columns in database and are automatically mapped by JPA.

`User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String pass;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "USERS_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "uploader")
    private Set<Book> books;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
    private Set<Message> inbox;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender")
    private Set<Message> outbox;
    //getters and setters
}
```

The problem is, when I select an `User` from Oracle database, then the `inbox` property is empty. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see if collections are populated regardless of JSF?

Comment: Yes I checked the size of the set and it is 0.

Comment: JSF isn't causing the problem. It's merely the presenter here. I removed the irrelevant JSF noise from the question and added the `[jpa]` tag to get the right attention.

Comment: What does your database contain? Where's the code used to load the user?

Comment: the code which loades the user entity is a datatable in a jsf page which was omitted by BalusC. my database has two tables : users and messages. message table has two foreign keys : sender and receiver both pointing to the id column of user table.

Comment: The datatable doesn't directly get data from the database I presume. It uses some part of your code which actually uses your entities and loads the data using JPA. That's the part you should show.

Comment: the datatable accepts a list as value attribute. in my question this list is loaded by the messages in inbox set which are the messages in database.